# Plotting Data from simulation using metadata

Tags: python, plot, metadata, simulation

So I have a simulation that produces data based representing a rigid bodies state, such as acceleration, velocity, position, quaternions etc. The simulation is written in C, and outputs data to a csv file. The first column is always the time of the simulation with the next columns being the vectors. Usually they would be 3 or 4 columns but I would like a solution that could extend for more.

I want to plot the data in python. But I also wanted to have a metadata file which would store information like title of plot, axis titles, axis limits etc. I have seen other projects not use csv files for this but ini files.

I was wondering what would be the best practice for this and what types of files should be used for storing metadata? Also what structure should the files take and what is general good practice?

Comment: Use a meta-language such as XML, YAML, etc.

Comment: Is there a standard way to format these files or is there not a standard practise? @pjs

Comment: They are plain text files containing syntactically correct meta-language data specifications. Details depend on the ML you choose. Python (and many other languages) provide libraries, so do some research, pick one, and RTFM (read the fine manual). Note that asking for recommendations is off-topic on this site.